# Java input stream

Tags: java, stream

I am trying to open a file through the following programcode

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    else if(e.getSource() == menyFlikTre)
    {
        läsInFil(textFalt.getText());
    }    


private void läsInFil(String filename)
{
    try {
        FileReader r = new FileReader(filename);
        textArea.read(r, null);
    }
    catch(IOException e){}
}
```

When i put in the name of the file with the .txt extension, it only adds the entire name of the file including the extension .txt instead of the content of the file.

Comment: I'm afraid this simply isn't possible with the code you're showing us. Please make sure the code you're running is the same code you're looking at -- you may have gotten mixed up with multiple  versions of things, or modifying the code without compiling it, etc. Also, *never* use empty catch blocks like that -- always include at least a call to `printStackTrace()` on the exception object, so you know if something goes wrong.

Comment: Is it ok to have that special `ä` character in `läsInFil`? I've never seen that before, so I just thought I'd point it out.

Comment: i just went through the rest of the code and it is irrelevant...

Comment: @kentcdodds Java allows any Unicode characters in its identifier names. In method and variable names it works just fine. Class names may sometimes cause problems, not because of Java but because of file systems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should loop thorough the content of the file and add it to the textArea :

```
FileReader fr = new FileReader(filename); 
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr); 
String s; 
while((s = br.readLine()) != null) { 
// write to textArea
}
```

Comment: @JohnnyHankgard, you can add whatever you want to a try catch statement. What I mean is, it's allowed and will compile :)

Answer (score 0):

```
private void läsInFil(String filename)
{
    try {
        File file = new File(filename);   
        FileReader r = new FileReader(filename);
        char[] buf = new char[(int)file.length()];
        r.read(buf);
        String contentString = new String(buf);
        textArea.append(contentString);
    }
    catch(IOException e){
e.printStacktrace();
}
    }
```

Comment: @JohnnyHankgard - Use `String contentString = new String( buf );` and it should be working.

Comment: sorry, i didnt declare that var. pls do it :), edsited answer

Comment: i think this should work fine. do something in the catch, try to find if any exception occurs!. i have added the stacktrace.